# Class and Array Problems

Tags: python

I am absolutely useless with python and I'm struggling to do what seems to be simple things.
I need to read a text file which contains a network routing table which contains the distance between each node on the network (below)

```
0,2,4,1,6,0,0
2,0,0,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,0,5,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0
6,5,0,1,0,5,5
0,0,5,1,5,0,0
0,0,0,0,5,0,0
```

I then need to assign it to a two dimensional array which I have done with the code i have written below..

```
Network = []
NodeTable = []
def readNetwork():
    myFile = open('network.txt','r')
    for line in myFile.readlines():
        line.strip(' \n' '\r') 
        line = line.split(',')
        line = [int(num) for num in line]
        Network.append(line)
```

Once that has been done I then need to iterate through the Network array and add each horizontal line to another array  which will hold information about the nodes, but as far as I have been able to get with that is here:

```
class Node(object):
     index = #Needs to start from A and increase with each node
     previousNode = invalid_node
     distFromSource = infinity
     visited = False


NodeTable.append(Node())
```

So that array will be initialised as:

```
A  invalid_node  infinity  False
B  invalid_node  infinity  False
C  invalid_node  infinity  False
...
etc
```

Could anyone give me a hand with creating each node in the NodeTable array?

Comment: What is your approach to creating the node table? Show us.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to know how to keep an index that increments between calls to `Node()`?

Comment: @Daniel: Don't add comments to your question.  **Update** your question to be clear and complete.  Include as much code or pseudo-code as you possibly can.  But don't add comments.

Comment: there are no "arrays" in Python, you probably meant `list`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Redundant line

Strings in Python are **immutable**, thus with the following line:

```
line.strip(' \n' '\r')
```

you are only getting a copy of the `line` string, stripped of some characters, but you do not assign it to anything. Change it into:

```
line = line.strip(' \n' '\r')
```

As DSM pointed out in the comments, it will not change much, as `int` will just ignore redundant whitespaces.

### Mapping string to `int`s

You also are mapping strings to `int`s like that:

```
line = [int(num) for num in line]
```

which could be replaced by clearer:

```
line = map(int, line)
```

and should give you some slight performance gain also. To shorten your code, you can also replace the following lines:

```
line.strip(' \n' '\r') 
line = line.split(',')
line = [int(num) for num in line]
Network.append(line)
```

with the following:

```
Network.append(map(int, line.split(',')))
```

### How to increase `Node`'s `index` attribute with each instance

This could be done like that:

```
>>> class Node(object):
    baseindex = '@'  # sign before "A"
    def __init__(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.baseindex = chr(ord(cls.baseindex) + 1)
        self.index = self.baseindex
        self.previousNode = 'invalid_node'
        self.distFromSource = 'infinity'
        self.visited = False


>>> a = Node()
>>> a.index
'A'
>>> b = Node()
>>> b.index
'B'
>>> a.index
'A'
```

As you can see `baseindex` is attached to the class, and `index` is attached to the class's instance. I suggest you should attach every instance-specific variable to the instance, as shown in the example above.

### Adding `Node` into the list as list

One of the easiest ways to insert it as list into another list, is to add a method returning it as list (see `as_list()` method):

```
>>> class Node(object):
    baseindex = '@'  # sign before "A"
    def __init__(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.baseindex = chr(ord(cls.baseindex) + 1)
        self.index = self.baseindex
        self.previousNode = 'invalid_node'
        self.distFromSource = 'infinity'
        self.visited = False
    def as_list(self):
        return [self.index, self.previousNode, self.distFromSource,
            self.visited]


>>> a = Node()
>>> a.index
'A'
>>> a.as_list()
['A', 'invalid_node', 'infinity', False]
```

so you should be able to add nodes like this:

```
NodeTable.append(Node().as_list())
```

But remember - after doing the above, you will not get list of `Node` instances, you will get list of lists.

Comment: int is perfecly happy with leading and trailing whitespace, so although this is a bug, it doesn't actually have any effect on his code.

Comment: @DSM: Ok, you are right in this case - but the fact is, that OP has lines that are not executed. I am in the process of updating my answer with additional notes.